# Compilation error in parallel implementation of std::accumulate

Tags: c++, multithreading

I wrote the following parallel implementation of `std::accumulate`, It's giving a compilation error.

error: called object type 'int' is not a function or function pointer
threads[i] = thread(batch_sum<Iterator, T>, block_start, block_end, ref(results[i]));
How do I fix this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>
#include <vector>

#define BATCH_SIZE 250

using namespace std;

template<typename Iterator, typename T>
void batch_sum(Iterator start, Iterator end, T &ref)
{
    ref = accumulate(start, end, 0);
}

template<typename Iterator, typename T>
T parallel_accumulate(Iterator start, Iterator end, T ref)
{
    unsigned input_size = distance(start, end);
    unsigned num_threads = input_size / BATCH_SIZE;
    unsigned hardware_threads = thread:: hardware_concurrency();
    num_threads = min(hardware_threads == 0 ? 2: hardware_threads, num_threads);
    vector<T> results(num_threads);

    vector<thread> threads(num_threads - 1);

    Iterator block_start;

    for(unsigned i = 0; i < num_threads - 1; ++i)
    {
        Iterator block_end = block_start;
        advance(block_end, BATCH_SIZE);
        threads[i] = thread(batch_sum<Iterator, T>, block_start, block_end, ref(results[i]));
        block_start = block_end;
    }

    results[num_threads - 1] = accumulate(block_start, end, 0);

    for_each(threads.begin(), threads.end(), mem_fn(&std:: thread:: join));

    return accumulate(results.begin(), results.end(), 0);
}

int main()
{
    vector<int> vec(28000, 0);
    cout << parallel_accumulate(begin(vec), end(vec), 0);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is expected here `ref(results[i])` with ref is 0?

Comment: In `ref(results[i])` you probably meant to use `std::ref`, but in fact you are trying to use the local variable `T ref`, which of course makes no sense. Either qualify the name in the function call, or rename the parameter.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but `Iterator block_start;` creates a singular iterator, i.e., an iterator that does not refer to any range. And the subsequent `Iterator block_end = block_start;` copies that iterator, so `block_end` is also singular.